# Any time a section is mentioned in the document, I want that mention to become a link to the corresponding bookmark

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

**Goal:** I have a very long document with many unique sections that each have bookmarks. Any time a section is mentioned in the document, I want that mention to become a link to the corresponding bookmark. It doesn't have to be event-driven, I intend to do it from a menu.

I have the below code written to get a list of the names of each bookmarked line so I can match it to the words in the doc. I'm trying to figure out what line of code to use to link specific text to that bookmark. I've tried to use the `setLinkUrl("beginningofurl" + id[i])` code, but the ID of the bookmarks doesn't tell me if it's a header or regular text, and sometimes it is just regular text. I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

```
var DOC = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();

function Setlink() {
  var bookmarks = DOC.getBookmarks();
  var names = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++){
    names.push(bookmarks[i].getPosition().getSurroundingText().getText());
  }
  Logger.log(names);
}
```

Comment: You have the words, now you need to find them in the document, by paragraph and position, and set the link Url. What is not working for you?

Comment: Try to get the style applied to the paragraph to see if it's " a header".

Answer (score 1):

Headings are a property of [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) elements.  To check a [Bookmark](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/bookmark) to see if it is in a paragraph of a certain [Paragraph Heading](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph-heading), we need to get the [Position](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/position), then the [Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element), and then check if the Element is indeed a Paragraph before we can check the Paragraph Heading.

We can put our test for if an Element is a heading in a predicate function named `isElementInHeading` that will return true or false when given an Element.

```js
function isElementInHeading(element) {
  if (element.getType() !== DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
    return false;
  }
  const {ParagraphHeading} = DocumentApp;
  switch (element.getHeading()) {
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING1:
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING2:
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING3:
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING4:
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING5:
    case ParagraphHeading.HEADING6:
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This can be used to both filter the bookmarks to include only those that mark headings, and to skip over the same headings when using `setLinkUrl`.

The strategy in this example is to collect both the bookmark's ID and the desired text in one go using a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function, then search through the document for each bit of text, check that we didn't just find the header again, and then apply the link.

I am not quite sure how you are getting the URL, but I found just copying and pasting the URL into the script as `const url = "https://docs.google.com/.../edit#bookmark=";` worked for me.

```js
// for Array.prototype.reduce
function getHeadingBookmarksInfo(bookmarks, bookmark) {
  const element = bookmark.getPosition().getElement();
  if (isElementInHeading(element)) {
    return [
      ...bookmarks,
      { id: bookmark.getId(), text: element.getText() }
    ];
  }
  return bookmarks;
}

function updateLinks() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const bookmarks = doc.getBookmarks();
  const headingBookmarksInfo = bookmarks.reduce(getHeadingBookmarksInfo, []);
  const body = doc.getBody();
  headingBookmarksInfo.forEach(function(info) {
    const {id, text} = info;
    let foundRef = body.findText(text);
    while (foundRef !== null) {
      const element = foundRef.getElement();
      if (!isElementInHeading(element.getParent())) {
        element.asText()
          .setLinkUrl(
            foundRef.getStartOffset(),
            foundRef.getEndOffsetInclusive(),
            url + id // assumes url is hardcoded in global scope
          );
      }
      foundRef = body.findText(text, foundRef);
    }
  });
}
```