# Google Apps Script - How to get the bookmark link?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to get the bookmark link after I run `addBookmark()` on Google Docs. I see that we cannot use the `getUrl()` for the bookmark. I'm thinking of using the id of bookmark but I am having trouble on the url.

My current code to get the bookmark link looks like this.

```
doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
bookmark = doc.addBookmark(position);
let bookmarklink = String(doc.getUrl() + '/edit#bookmark=' + boomark.getId());
```

Is there any other implementation that is more dynamic? I would like for it to work on test (test deploy), my problem is that I get a different url from `doc.getUrl()` on test.

thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63029413/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322073/1595451

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, it is somehow related but it isn't the answer that I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getUrl()` returns the URL like `https://docs.google.com/open?id={fileId}`. On the other hand, the hyperlink of bookmark is like `https://docs.google.com/document/d/{fileId}/edit#bookmark=id.{bookmarkId}`. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to retrieve the bookmark URL, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let bookmarklink = String(doc.getUrl() + '/edit#bookmark=' + boomark.getId());
```

#### To:

```
let bookmarklink = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getUrl().replace("?usp=drivesdk", "#bookmark=" + boomark.getId());
```

or

```
let bookmarklink = `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${doc.getId()}/edit#bookmark=${boomark.getId()}`;
```